# Error while passing parameters to the constructor of the base class of a component in angular 2/4 using inheritance

Tags: angular, oop, typescript, inheritance

I am using inheritance in typescript with angular 4 to extend a derived class component from the base class. But whenever i try to pass a variable/property to my constructor of base class and `ngc` compile the project, it gives me an error of-

```
Can't resolve all parameters for BaseComponent in C:/path/src/components/base_component/base_component.component.ts
```

My base class-

```
export class BaseComponent {
    // Input values
    @Input() selectedOption: string;
    @Input() data : object;
    @Input() disabled : boolean;
    @Input() title: string;

    eventDetails : object = {
        type: 'onOptionChange',
        name: 'base_dropdown',
        value: '',
    };

    // Component output
    @Output() onOptionChange: EventEmitter<object> = new EventEmitter<object>();

    constructor(public eventName : any) {
        this.eventDetails["name"] = eventName;
    }
    ngOnChanges() {
        if(this.data && !this.selectedOption) {
            this.selectedOption = this.dropdownValue(this.data[0]);
        }
    }
    dropdownValue(option : any) {
        if(option.id == -1 ) {
            return option.name;
        }
        else {
            return option.id
        }
    }

    onModelChange(selectedOption : any) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.eventDetails);

        this.eventDetails["value"] = selectedOption;
        this.onOptionChange.emit(this.eventDetails);
    }
}
```

My derived class-

```
@Component({
  selector: 'character-style-dropdown',
  template: `
        <base-dropdown
            [disabled]="disabled"
            [selectedOption]="selectedOption"
            [data]="characterStyleConfig"
            [title]="title"
            (onOptionChange)="this.onOptionChange.emit($event)">
        </base-dropdown>
    `
})

export class CharacterStyleDropdown extends BaseComponent {
    characterStyleConfig : object;
    title = "Character Style:";

    constructor (
        private getStyleListService : GetStyleListService
    ) {
        super("character_dropdown");
        this.getStyleListService.getStyles("getCharacterStyle")
        .subscribe(
            (styles : object) => this.characterStyleConfig = styles["styles"] ,
            (error : any) => console.log(error)
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Also, this way of inheritance works in another case where i am inheriting some component into some other component. But in this case it fails. Is it maybe because i am inheriting this base component into 7 other components, but i have `super("string")` in all of them.
Is there any way of may be default initialize the property of constructor so it won't have to resolve parameters in case i didn't provide any ?

How can i fix this error ?

Comment: Please, add code for the derived class implementation. How are you trying to extend your `BaseComponent` class?

Comment: I have added the code and tried to explain even better of the problem i am facing. @OsmanCea

Comment: Also one thing i think i have figured out is that, maybe because i am also using my `BaseComponent` as it is also, that may be causing some issue as well. As in i have exported the component and consuming it from another angular project.

Comment: As far as I know, both your base class and your child class have to be part of the same module, so you're gonna get problems if you're importing the base class from someplace else

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 super(<any>"character_dropdown");
```